# Why is my ViewModel null in Fragment but not Fragment's bound layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, fragment, viewmodel

I have a `FooActivity: AppCompatActivity()` that uses a `FooViewModel` to look up a `Foo` from a database and then present information about it in a few `Fragment`s. Here's how I set it up:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: FooViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the FOO_ID
    val id = intent.getLongExtra(FOO_ID, 1L)
    val viewModelFactory = FooViewModelFactory(
        id,
        FooDatabase.getInstance(application).fooDao,
        application)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
        this, viewModelFactory).get(FooViewModel::class.java)

    // FooViewModel is bound to Activity's Fragments, so must
    // create FooViewModelFactory before trying to bind/inflate layout
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_foo)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
}
```

And in the `FooInfoFragment` class:

```
private val viewModel: FooViewModel by activityViewModels()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    val binding = FragmentFooInfoBinding.inflate(inflater)
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    // normally viewModel.foo shouldn't be null here, right?
    return binding.root
}
```

So far so good. My layout shows the various info of the `Foo`, eg `@{viewModel.foo.name}`.

The issue is that in my `FooInfoFragment.onCreateView` when I attempt to access `viewModel.foo.value?.name` after binding, `viewModel` is null.

```
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    Log.wtf(TAG, "${viewModel.foo.value?.name} shouldn't be null!")
    return binding.root
```

I don't understand why it's null in my Fragment but not in my layout. Help?

Comment: `activityViewModels()`(i suppose this is from fragemnt-ktx ) has its own implementation i think its failing to create one since you have a parameterized constructor.

Comment: @ADM I know the viewModel is getting created `by activityViewModels()` because I am seeing the `Foo` information being rendered in the `Fragment` layout after binding. `activityViewModels()` uses a `ViewModelFactory` to create the `ViewModel`. See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#7

Comment: Is it really the viewmodel that is null? In the line `viewModel.foo.value?.name`, it could be also `foo` or `foo.value`. And if it were `viewmodel` or `viewModel.foo`, the app would crash.

Comment: `viewModel` itself  is null? or the `viewModel.foo.value?.name` is null? if `viewModel.foo.value` then it might be because the live data is not set yet. Aka the data from the database is not loaded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines here that your problem is that you don't expect `viewModel.foo.value` to be nullable, not that you are getting a Java NPE for a null `viewModel` when you access `viewModel.foo`.

If `foo` is a LiveData, its `value` parameter is always nullable, even if its type is not. That is how the LiveData class is defined. `value` is nullable because it defaults to null before it has been set. After it is set, it won't be null again. If you are sure that you always set its value before accessing it, you can use `value!!` or `value ?: error("Value was accessed before it was set.")`.

Or you can write an extension property to access it more cleanly:

```
val <T: Any> LiveData<T>.requiredValue: T get() = 
    value ?: error("Non-null value cannot be accessed before value is first set.")
```

However, LiveData values should rarely need to be accessed directly. The intent with LiveData is that changes to the value will be observed, in which case, you would never run into this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The root cause what that the async operation to fetch the Foo from the database hadn't terminated at the time onCreate returned, but did terminate before rendering (so all the LiveData in the layout rendered correctly, making me forget that these data's availability depended on the async operation).

Comment: hey need help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537639/spinner-value-using-retrofit-and-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

The "viewModel" in FooInfoFragment Fragment is not yet initialized and that's why it's null in Fragment.

```
binding.viewModel = viewModel 
//ViewModel is not initialized
```

Comment: `by activityViewModels()` guarantees that it is initialized when you access it the first time.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Really.. 
Now @Tenfour04 viewModel.LiveData.value will always be null outside Observer even if it is not nullable (I learned it the hard way). It can only confirm that it holds data while in an Observer. 
If you want to use one-shot asynchronous operations than use Flow or Transformations.switchMap.